# Infinite loop C, infinite loop

Tags: c

I've a problem with loop on C. I've an infinite loop withe this code...

```
int nb3=0;

while ((nb3 <=0) || (nb3 > 100) || (isdigit(nb3) && (isdigit(nb3) !=0)) )    
{
    printf("%d\n", nb3);
    nb3=1;
    printf("%d\n", nb3);
    printf("Le nombre saisi est incorrect, veuillez le ressaisir \n");
    scanf("%d",&nb3);
}
```

Comment: Did you execute this code? Do you know what is `infinite loop`?

Comment: i executed this code, and I thing the infinite loop is around "scanf("%d",&nb3);".
I can't write a new number in nb3 with this scanf.

Comment: The `scanf` ask for user input. What was your input  to the program (in the console)? And did you hit enter?

Comment: The number you enter must be `>0 && <48` or `>57 && <=100`. What did you enter?

Comment: Also, what are you attempting with `isdigit(nb3) && (isdigit(nb3) !=0)`? That part doesn't make sense. Well, it does, but it does the same test twice.

Comment: the beginning programs before while is : 

  float x3;
    float f3 = sin(0);
    int nb3=0 ;
    short i3 ;
    double tmp;


    FILE *hfile3; //pointeur pour le fichier

    hfile3 = fopen ("question12.txt", "w");  //ouvre le fichier question12 en écriture

    printf("rentrer le nombre \n");
    scanf("%d",&nb3);               //permet la saisie

Comment: if I enter a letter to test or a float, I have this infinite loop

Comment: Please edit you question and include the code you have just posted in the comment.

Comment: @MartinZabel The code was already there, but someone edited it away.

Comment: @ThomasLemonnier You can't enter a letter with `scanf("%d"...` The quick solution is to enter the ASCII code of the letter (i.e. 65 for A, etc.) Another solution would be to use `%c` in the scanf, but then you couldn't enter numbers like 99 any more. Also, you can't input a float into an int.

Comment: I have executed your code. If I enter an integer, `nb3` is updated and the loop is exited if `nb3>0 && nb3 <48`  or `nb3>57 && nb3 <=100`, otherwise the loop is re-excuted. If a enter a letter or a float `nb3` is still 1, so that the loop is exited.

Comment: @MartinZabel Good point about starting with a letter. Examples of inputs that will cause a problem are `123abc` and `123.4`. In any case, this question is a duplicate of about 182 other question concerning scanf infinite loops, which can be found by searching for `[c] scanf infinite`.

Comment: tnak's for your help, I've just to find the answer.
I define nb3 on char, i do the while with char and before the while I change char on a int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bizarre issues with your code. The **intent** of your code appears to be to ask the user to enter a number that is either negative or greater than 100. If the user enters a number on the range `[0,100]` or a non-number (ie: a letter/character), the loop breaks out.

First, the `scanf()` call leaves a newline in the input buffer. Issues with `gets()`, `fgets()`, and `scanf()` are common beginner questions on StackOverflow. However, there's one other bug in your code, so I'm not marking it as a 100% duplicate yet.

Your check, `(isdigit(nb3) && (isdigit(nb3) !=0)`, looks wrong. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with `isdigit(nb3) != 0`, but it has no valid purpose as far as I can see, as you've already tested `nb3` with the function. Also, `isdigit()` is usually used when checking individuals characters in a string for whether they represent numeric values. Your use of it seems wrong.

An updated code listing is provided below which should fix the infinite loop behavior I presume you're encountering.

---

## Code Listing

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int nb3 = 0;

    while ( (nb3 <=0) || (nb3 > 100) || isdigit(nb3) )
    {
        printf("%d\n", nb3);
        nb3=1;
        printf("%d\n", nb3);
        printf("Le nombre saisi est incorrect, veuillez le ressaisir \n");
        scanf("%d", &nb3);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: THANK'S for your updated code @Dogbert , I check this morning and It work. My programm work too.